# How do I migrate personal settings (.mozilla) from Snap's Firefox to APT Firefox?

Tags: firefox, snap

In Ubuntu 22.04, the default Firefox installation is the Snap version. It is possible to migrate from the Snap version of Firefox to the APT version (.deb), by following the instructions in this article: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

However, that article doesn't explain how to migrate the personal Firefox settings from Snap to the APT version. Firefox installed by Snap stores its settings here:

```
~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox
```

However, Firefox installed by APT (.deb) stores its settings here:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox
```

How do I migrate the settings from the former place to the latter place? Simply copying the directory does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by:

1. Backing up `~/snap/firefox/`
2. Removing the snap and installing the apt version of firefox
3. Replacing `~/.mozilla/firefox/` with the content of `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/`
4. At this point, firefox somehow still starts with a fresh new profile (even if you replaced the files). Go to `about:profiles` and set your old profile as the default one
5. Restart firefox

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply moving the directory `.mozilla/firefox` in `~/snap/firefox/common/` to `~` *will* work. Of course, no instance of firefox should be running while you do the move.

Comment: You need to do this *before* running `snap remove firefox`, as that command will delete most files in `~/snap/firefox/` .

Comment: I tried it just now, and it didn't work for me. When I opened Firefox (APT), it ran as if for the first time, with default settings and a welcome screen.

Comment: Very strange, because Firefox looks in `~/.mozilla/firefox` and creates that directory if it does not exist. Something else must be going on.

Comment: I typically edit profiles.ini & installs.ini. It used to be just profiles.ini. You have to change from the default profile it creates with new install & load to old profile you copied. You can also from within Firefox choose a profile, but do not know details anymore. I use same profile in multiple installs for years. Back with XP I has same profile for Windows & Ubuntu and never had issues even if not same version, But now I sometimes get version issues, so make sure you have good backup of profile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to migrate from SNAP version of FF to the APT version in 22.04 was to have already set up a Firefox account.

On opening Firefox you should then be in a position to log in to your account and all your saved bookmarks will be there.